# How to get the index of snapshot on child added?

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
...
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
  //I would like to know what snapshot it is, by index
});
...
```

What can I use to get the index of `snapshot` in `myDataRef` on child added?

Comment: Don't know if you can get the index. But you can get the name of the previous sibling child by passing a second parameter to the callback. Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a Firebase collection **children are identified by their name**, not by their index. You **can** use numeric names, but your code snippet does not show whether you do that.

If you're looking for the name (the thing that identifies the child under `myDataRef`) then you can get it from `snapshot.name()`.

So you also get the name of the current child:

```
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
  var nameOfThisChild = snapshot.name();
});
```

If you stored the item in a node with a numeric name, you can parse the name into a number with:

```
parseInt(nameOfThisChild)
```

You can also get the `ref` of the child snapshot directly:

```
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
  var refToThisChild = snapshot.ref(); 
  // equivalent to myDataRef.child(snapshot.name())
});
```

As always: be sure to read the documentation on [how Firebase handles arrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase).

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question: can I update some property of snapshot with some data?

Comment: Sure. You'll want to use `update`, which allows you to just specify a few properties (patching the object, instead of replacing it): `snapshot.ref().update({ newprop: newvalue });` See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html