# Why do my signed URLs get an error 403?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Reference: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/0.8.0/storage/file?method=getSignedUrl

This is extremely strange. I did set my service account as having read permission of the storage objects.

What is going on ?

**server:**

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            titleArray.push(childSnapshot.val().title);
            usernameArray.push(childSnapshot.val().username);
            keyArray.push(childSnapshot.key);
            var file = bucket.file(childSnapshot.val().image);
            var config = {
              action: 'read',
              expires: Date.now() + 10000,
              contentType: 'image/png'
            };

            file.getSignedUrl(config, function(err, url) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }
                imageArray.push(url);
                if (imageArray.length == 9) {
                    res.render("home", {keyArray: keyArray, titleArray: titleArray, usernameArray: usernameArray, imageArray: imageArray});
                }
            });
        });
```

**client:**

```
$(".homeImage").each(function(i) {
            var row = $(this)
            row.attr('id', i);
            if (i == 4) {

            } else {
                $("#"+i).css('background-image', "url('" + imageArray[i]  + "')");
            }
        });
```

---

Response:

[image]

This is extremely strange since I thought signed URLs were supposed to authenticate my request as being sent by my service account.

Comment: What is the result you are seeing?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify, what is the body of the error response?  Generally there is some XML with some more details.

Comment: @royalpeasantry True. It says anonymous users are not allowed to access this resource. Which is truly extremely strange since I have authorised my service account to access my bucket objects and I am using signed urls which should provide some sort of authentication.

Comment: @royalpeasantry I edited my question with a screenshot.

Comment: The error message implies that your request doesn't have any authentication associated with it.  For a Signed URL that would mean that the GoogleAccessId/Signature/Expires query parameters are not set.  I'd debug print the image array server side and client side to see where it is getting lost.

Comment: @royalpeasantry That's the issue: I already checked. All the query paramaters are there including accessID. Even at the last stage, in the background-image url: all is there. That's why I am so confused.

Comment: @royalpeasantry I think you put me on the right track. For some reason, all the "&" are replaced by "&amp;"

Comment: @royalpeasantry That was it. Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message implies that your request doesn't have any authentication associated with it. For a Signed URL that would mean that the GoogleAccessId/Signature/Expires query parameters are not set.

I'd debug print the image array server side and client side to see where it is getting lost.

Edit: In this case it looks like `&` was being replaced with `&amp;` somewhere.